# Loop through multiple named ranges and cell values to control various PowerPoint formatting parameters=

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint, excel-2013

I need to paste multiple (approximately 70) named ranges from Excel to PowerPoint as pictures. Each picture may have a different height, width, position, and destination slide. I will have all of the parameters in an Excel Sheet. For example:

- Column A: list of all named ranges (NamedRange1)
- Column B: cell references of the named ranges (Sheet1:$A$1:$B$4)
- Column C: Destination slide number
- Column D-G: values to control sizing and position parameters

I have spent a significant amount of time researching both on stack overflow and other sites for a solution and have pieced together the code below which works for a single named range, but I would like to find a solution that utilizes looping or arrays (or anything else) to avoid copying and pasting the code 70 times and manually updating the named ranges and cell references.

Assumptions: The user will have only 1 excel workbook open and 1 instance of powerpoint that already contains the appropriate number of slides.

Can the overlords of StackOverflow help?

```
Sub test()

Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.slide
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")


''define destination slide
SlideNum = Range("C2")
PPPres.Slides(SlideNum).Select
Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

' Copy the range as a picture
XLApp.[namerange1].Copy
' Paste the range
PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select

' Align the pasted range
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = Range("D2")
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = Range("E2")

' Align the shape
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Range("G2")
PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = Range("F2")
' Clean up
Set PPSlide = Nothing
Set PPPres = Nothing
Set PPApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I suggest you try something like the code below. You can extract all Named Ranges with the `ActiveWorkbook.Names` collection as per:

```
Dim nms as Range
Set nms = ActiveWorkbook.Names 

Dim r as Integer
For r = 1 To nms.Count 
    Dim PPApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim PPPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.slide
    Dim SlideNum As Integer
    Set XLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")


    ''define destination slide
    SlideNum = Range("C2")
    PPPres.Slides(SlideNum).Select
    Set PPSlide = PPPres.Slides(PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)

    ' Copy the range as a picture
    XLApp.[nms(r)].Copy
    ' Paste the range
    PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile).Select

    ' Align the pasted range
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Height = Range("D2")
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Width = Range("E2")

    ' Align the shape
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Left = Range("G2")
    PPApp.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Top = Range("F2")
    ' Clean up
    Set PPSlide = Nothing
    Set PPPres = Nothing
    Set PPApp = Nothing
Next
```

You might have to adapt your code inside the loop as I only edited references to the Named ranges. Hard coded destination ranges might have to be changed to dynamic destinations depending on your desired results. More information on the Name collection in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841280.aspx. Hope you find this useful. Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

I have a commercial add-in that does something like this, among other things; the approach there is a bit different, but what you might consider here is to add rectangles in PowerPoint wherever you want the Excel content to appear.  The size and position of the rectangles can dictate the size/position of the pasted Excel content.  The text in the rectangles can indicate the name of the Excel range that's to be copied into PPT in place of the rectangle (which you'll delete afterwards).

BTW, you never EVER want to select anything in PPT if you don't have to.  Slows everything down by an order of magnitude and complicates things.  Instead use constructs like:

```
Dim oSh as PowerPoint.Shape
Set oSh = PPSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile)(1)
With oSh
   ' set the properties 
End With
```